# How to dump non-zero elements of a sparse matrix into a non-sparse matrix

Tags: matlab, octave

I could have also asked how to dump a sparse matrix to CSV basically I have a graph represented as a sparse matrix and I want to export the graph to CSV to open it in Gephi. So my sparse matrix is something like:

```
(23,35) 1

(35,78) 1

(78,23) 1
```

etc

I would like to convert this into a vector like:
`[23,35,1;35,78,1;78,23,1]`

I would love to know there's a simple one-liner to do it but I can't make my brain find it so thanks a lot for the help.

If you alternatively known something as `sparse2csv('graph.csv',Adj)` that would generate in a file:

```
23,35,1

35,78,1

78,23,1
```

Then that would work too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The way that comes to mind isn't a one-liner (though it could easily be made one via a function) but simply uses two function calls: [`find`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/find.html) and [`nonzeros`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/nonzeros.html):

```
A       = sparse([23;35;78],[35;78;23],[1;1;1]);
[r,c]   = find(A~=0);
v       = nonzeros(A);
compact = [r,c,v];
disp(compact);
```

which returns

```
78    23     1
23    35     1
35    78     1
```

---

As  Luis Mendo points out in the comments, a simpler solution exists since `find` will return the nonzero values in a third output argument (the given array is no longer logical either now):

```
[r,c,v] = find(A);
compact = [r,c,v];
```

Comment: Thanks! I still can't believe there's a one line function to do this. Maybe is not so common :)

Comment: @user3635284 Well, that only popular use of this potential function (that I can think of) is for exporting to a text file.

Comment: Perhaps simpler: `[r,c,v]   = find(A);` (no need for `nonzeros`)